# Программа с палиндромом на C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Выяснить, есть ли данное число (введённое) полиндромом, то есть таким что 
десятичное написание, читается одинаково, слева на право и справа налево. (473374)
Я понимаю что нужно сделать, нужна формула делающая выборка каждого символа в начале и в конце числа, сверяющая и идущая далее. Но как эту формулу написать я не понимаю.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long x;
    cout << "Введите число - ";
    cin >> x;
    if (x % 10 == x) 
    {
        /*Вот здесь наибольшая проблема с какого числа начать, ведь по сути заданное число может изчислятся сотнями,а может десятками тысяч"*/
    }
}
```

Помогайте, критикуйте, буду рад всему.

Comment: Вы не знаете как определять палиндром? Поделите строку на две части и разверните одну из частей.

Comment: Проще всего введенное число считать и оставить строкой - так проще определить палиндромность :)